# PXE Boot Broken after 12.04 Upgrade

Tags: pxe

I had a system booting over the network with PXE on 11.10. I upgrade to 12.04 and now the boot fails during startup with the following messsage:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:

-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
-Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/nfs does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

My PXE config file is:

```
default linux

say Starting Legolas

LABEL linux
KERNEL legolas/vmlinuz
APPEND netboot=nfs root=/dev/nfs initrd=legolas/initrd.img nfsroot=192.168.0.8:/srv/tftp/legolas,rsize=4096,wsize=4096 ip=dhcp pci=nomsi rw quiet
```

Any ideas why this does not work on 12.04? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correcting the pxeconfig line enabled the system:

```
APPEND boot=nfs root=/dev/nfs initrd=legolas/initrd.img nfsroot=192.168.0.8:/srv/tftp/legolas,rsize=4096,wsize=4096 ip=dhcp pci=nomsi rw quiet
```

The change from above was only `boot=nfs`

I also want to point out that [DisklessUbuntuHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto) does not mention the `boot=nfs` parameter, and I could not get the system to boot without it. I hope someone with the same issues finds this before they waste too much time.

Comment: Are you sure this was the issue? I'm booting 12.04 from PXE fine without `boot=nfs`. My line: `APPEND root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=1.2.3.4:/path/to/ubu1204 initrd=ubuntu/12.04/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic ip=dhcp rw --` (removed hardware specific workarounds unrelated to PXE). Maybe the unneeded (or even wrong?) `netboot` parameter was causing it instead.